# I am getting an error with my C++ Window

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, window

Right, recently i have been learning c++ because i would like to make a game. So what i did, i started of by making a c++ window however at the end of making it i came up with a problem that i cannot fix. On the line where it says wc.lpszClassName = L"ZakariyaTV's Class"; i get a red line underneath the equals. I spent soo much time trying to figure it out but i cant. If you know how to fix it it would really appreciated. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
#include<Windows.h>

HWND windowHandle;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE preInstance, PSTR cmdLine, int showCmd)
{
    // Step 1

    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hIconSm = 0;

    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"ZakariyaTV's Class";
    wc.lpszMenuName = 0;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);

    // Step 2 
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    // Step 3
    windowHandle = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES, L"ZakariyaTV's Class", L"Game!",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 100, 100, 800, 600, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);

    // Step 4 

    if (windowHandle == 0)
        MessageBoxA(0, "Create window failed", "Error Message", 0);

    // Step 5 

    ShowWindow(windowHandle, showCmd);

    // Step 6

    UpdateWindow(windowHandle);

    MSG msg;

    SecureZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(MSG));
    int returnValue = 0;

    while ((returnValue = GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) != 0)
    {
        if (returnValue == -1)
        {
            MessageBoxA(windowHandle, "GetMessage Failed!", "Error Message", 0);
            break;
        }

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);


    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: It's nice that the IDE underlines it, but what *error message* does the compiler produce for this line when you try to compile the code? Also, please format your code example properly.

Comment: My guess? You're not building with `UNICODE` set.

Comment: its says this : https://gyazo.com/071258b37abe17a3c5e996c9d163846b

Comment: The [`WNDCLASSEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure member `lpszClassName` is defined to be a [`LPCTSTR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#LPCTSTR), which can be either of two things depending on if you're building with the `UNICODE` macro defined or not. There is a reason the [`TEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (or its alias `T`) macro exists.

Comment: Please read more about [Unicode and how it's used when programming in Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374081%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: so what do you want me to do? Do you want me to replace lpszClassName with LPCTSTR? If yes then it does not work...

Comment: Use _T("...") instead of L"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015 use Multi-Byte Character Set for default when you create a new project, but the L in L"ZakariyaTV's Class" is tell the compiler that the string should be compiled as Unicode, so you should change the Character Set for your project: right click project in VS 2015, then choose Properties->General->Character set under  Project Defaults, finally change your previous "Use Multi-Byte Character Set" to "Use Unicode Character Set".

Comment: New projects are created in Unicode by default in VS 2015

Comment: I would like to just say thank you! I tried it and it worked! Thank you.